# AdMob on Landscape

Tags: iphone, admob, landscape-portrait

My app is having AdMob on both modes i.e. landscape & Portrait.When my app launch on landscape mode it gives

Must set the rootViewController property of GADBannerView before calling loadRequest:

And ads doesn't appears on any modes

It is working fine when app launches on portrait mode and after that on rotating landscape modes ads are appearing.

Comment: Is your code doing something funky where it is in fact not setting the rootViewController property before calling loadRequest in landscape mode?

Comment: I found the same issue today. Have you find the reason and the solution?

Comment: Check out this answer for the same problem yo have
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25003492/7105612