# Google Mobile Ads SDK 6.10.0: <Google> Must set the rootViewController property of GADBannerView before calling loadRequest

Tags: ios7, admob

This error just started showing up following upgrade to 6.10.0, so a different issue to the other questions reporting this same issue. I've walked through the code and setting the Root View Controller of the GADBannerView doesn't take effect:

```
    [self.adUnit setRootViewController:controller];
    NSLog(@"Ad Unit:          %@", [self.adUnit class]);
    NSLog(@"Root VC:          %@", [controller class]);
    NSLog(@"Ad Unit Root VC:  %@", [self.adUnit.rootViewController class]);
```

Results in:

```
2014-07-25 11:52:23.234 *** [16665:607] Ad Unit:          GADBannerView
2014-07-25 11:52:23.235 *** [16665:607] Root VC:          MyAppViewController
2014-07-25 11:52:23.235 *** [16665:607] Ad Unit Root VC:  (null)
```

Comment: Cross posted to Google Group: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/community/?place=msg%2Fgoogle-admob-ads-sdk%2FZLRcrBxPLcs%2FTcoQtDBzZ48J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heard from Google:

"I checked with the engineers who said this is fixed at our head revision. They're still investigating why it happened in the first place though.

I don't have a date yet for when we'll be doing another release, so in the short term I'd recommend rolling back to 6.9 to address your immediate issue."

Ben

Comment: No longer an issue in 6.12.2, and probably earlier than that

Comment: Getting this issue in the device in 6.12.2 and 7.0.0. Any solutions yet?